# Wx widgets resource file error

Tags: wxwidgets

I am facing this annoying error 
"Fatal error rc1015: cannot open include file wx/msw/rcdefs.h".

I am on Windows 10 and visual studio 12. Anybody has an idea about this.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to compile the library, a sample or your own code?

Comment: also what version of the library you are trying?

Answer (score 1):

You have almost surely (because you don't say that you did it, when this would really be the first thing to check) forgot to specify the correct include paths for your resource compiler. Just add `$(WXWIN)/include` to the list of directories searched by it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, Go to the

*Project -> Properties -> Resources -> General -> Additional Include Directories*

and add the include path of wxwidget `(wxwidgets path/include)` to it.